# No display of database names using php by a dropbown

Tags: php, sql-server-2012

The names of the database in sql server is not displaying in the drop down.
Here are the codes.can you suggest a solution. thanks

```
<body>
    <?php

     $query = "SELECT [name] FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE dbid > 4";
     $params = array();
     $options =  array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );
     $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, $params, $options );

     echo '<select name="test" style="width: 100px;>';  

      while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array ($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
          {
            //unset($code);
            //$code= $row['ORG_CODE'];
              echo '<option value="'.$row['name'].'</option>'; 
          }
      echo '</select>';     
    ?>
```

Comment: missing `"` for style attribute in select tag.

Comment: Your setting the value of the option but no display value: echo '<option value="'.$row['name'].'</option>';  change to echo '<option value="'.$row['name'].'>'.$row['name'].'</option>';

Comment: it is displaying only one database name although i have put it in a while loop